# cython.parallel: variable assignment without thread-locality

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

Using [`cython.parallel`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html) I am looking to assign a shared-memory variable value from the `prange`-threads without the implicit thread-locality.

Or formulated more differently:

- how can I define a variable as openmp `shared` rather than `private` with `cython.parallel`?
- how can different threads or a `prange` block communicate?

---

Some very simple (and useless) pseudo-code to help illustrate my issue:

```
cdef void some_func(*data, ...)
  found = 0
  for i in parallel.prange(no_of_chunks):
    for j in range(10000):
      if found == 1:
        break    # assuming break only quits its own for loop...
      if data[i*chunk_size+j] == something
        found = 1
```

The idea in the above code segment is that each task checks the shared-memory variable `found` while it is processing its chunk. (Which may be large and thus take a long time to complete fully.) As soon as a single thread has found what it is looking for it sets the shared-memory variable `found` causing all other threads to exist instantly.

Unfortunately as I understand the doc, this is not what will happen:

> If you assign to a variable in a prange block, it becomes lastprivate,
>   meaning that the variable will contain the value from the last
>   iteration.

As I understand, this means that the above code segment works as follows:
- one thread finds what it is looking for, sets `found` and exits
- all other threads continue to use their thread-local version of `found` and continue processing

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: As described [elsewhere in the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html#breaking-out-of-loops), `break` will break out of *all* iterations, not just the current thread's iteration.  It's not clear to me why you need the `found` flag at all.

Comment: @Kevin The code segment was not supposed to run but merely to give something to illustrate what I was talking about. That said, I clearly chose a poor example to illustrate my point. I will think about how to reformulate the question to be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming one wanted to make `x` shared in the following piece of code:

```
from cython.parallel import prange

cdef:
    Py_ssize_t i, n = 100
    int x = 0

with nogil:
    for i in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
        x = 1
```

A problem arises as cython detects the assignment `x = 1` and automatically infers `x` to be `lastprivate` using:

```
#pragma omp for lastprivate(x)
```

To avoid this, assignment to a dereference pointer to `x` can be used:

```
from cython.parallel import prange
from cython import address

cdef:
    Py_ssize_t i, n = 100
    int x = 0
    int * px = address(x)

with nogil:
    for i in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
        px[0] = 1
```

Of course, access to the shared resource `x` now has to be managed manually. Above code is not functional in this respect.